# Echo entire pre-compiled php page

Tags: php

For example if I had the script:

```
<?php

     $page = "My Page";
     echo "<title>" . $page . "</title>";
     require_once('header.php');
     require_once('content.php');
     require_once('footer.php');


?>
```

Is there something I can add to the bottom of that page to show the entire pre-compiled php?

I want to literally echo the php code, and not compile it.

So in my browser I would see the following in code form...

```
// stuff from main php
$page = "My Page";
echo "<title>" . $page . "</title>";

// stuff from require_once('header.php');
$hello = "Welcome to my site!";
$name = "Bob";
echo "<div>" . $hello . " " . $name . "</div>";

// stuff from require_once('content.php');
echo "<div>Some kool content!!!!!</div>";

// stuff from require_once('footer.php');
$footerbox = "<div>Footer</div>";
echo $footerbox;
```

**Is this possible?**

Comment: I dont know if compiled is the right word but, what I mean is -- I want to see the php in php form rather than the final output form which displays for users viewing the site, which has already been "compiled".

Comment: I was honestly just curious, but I know what you mean. Probably "interpreted" is a better word.

Comment: This is an absurd question.  You can't say that you want to process includes at the beginning of the page, and then end saying that you don't want to process anything on the page.  You're contradicting yourself.  Can you explain why you're trying to do this?  Maybe there's a better way to achieve your end goal.

Comment: I am debugging... the php code CAN processed at the top, but is there also a way to show the pre-processed code at the bottom, -or- is there a way to output the code form as it happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do it native to PHP, but you could try to hack it if you just wanted something extremely simplistic and non-robust:

```
<?php
$php = file_get_contents($_GET['file']);

$php = preg_replace_callback('#^\s*(?:require|include)(?:_once)?\((["\'])(?P<file>[^\\1]+)\\1\);\s*$#m', function($matches) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($matches['file']);
    return preg_replace('#<\?php(.+?)(?:\?>)?#s', '\\1', $contents);
}, $php);

echo '<pre>', htmlentities($php), '</pre>';
```

**Notes:**

- **Warning:** Allowing arbitrary file parsing like I've done with the fist line is a security hole.  Do your own authentication, path restricting, etc.
- This is not recursive (though it wouldn't take much more work to make it so), so it won't handle included files within other included files and so on.
- The regex matching is not robust, and very simplistic.
- The included files are assumed to be statically named, within strings.  Things like `include($foo);` or `include(__DIR__ . '/foo.php');` will not work.

*Disclaimer: Essentially, to do this right, you need to actually parse the PHP code.  I only offer the above because it was an interesting problem and I was bored.*

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '$page = "My Page";';
echo 'echo "<title>" . $page . "</title>";';
echo file_get_contents('header.php');
echo file_get_contents('content.php');
echo file_get_contents('footer.php');
```

For clarity I'd put the title generation in it's own file, then just use a series of echo file_get_contents()...

```
echo file_get_contents('title.php');
echo file_get_contents('header.php');
echo file_get_contents('content.php');
echo file_get_contents('footer.php');
```